# Why Unity 3D in Natty doesnt have the same accordion effect we saw in Unity in Ubuntu 10.10 netbook edition

Tags: unity

the accordion effect seen in unity in Ubuntu 10.10 netbook edition is fantastic.
when you hover the mouse on the icons folded in the bottom of the unity panel they expand while the icons on the top of the unity panel (usually the home folder and firefox) fold in a accordion effect and stay like this for as long as you want them to stay folded. you can see what i am talking about [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/netbook/features)

in the new unity 3D in natty this is not implemented. only the icons at the bottom of the unity panel stay folded permanently (because of the gravity force i guess :)) ) while the icons in the upper part never get folded. when u hover the mouse over them they expand but the icons of the upper part of the unity panel don't fold in an accordion effect but they get out of site over the ubuntu logo in the upper panel.
that was a fantastic feature of unity une 10.10 that is not implemented in unity in natty and i want to ask why?
and something else.
take a look at the unity icons on UNE 10.10 at the link provided. they look fantastic, colorful, sexy. the current icons in the Natty's unity are simply super ugly and i still don't know why.
update !!! this is what i was looking 4 in the natty's unity. it is made by ubuntu and u can make it again work the same way in the other releases of unity i guess :)). the second video in this [link](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/perlow/ubuntu-linux-1104-a-whale-of-changes-for-canonicals-user-base/16125). isnt that great????

Answer (score 7):

I think you're right, we can make the accordion a little classier in 11.10. There's no way to switch the behaviour in 11.04 now I'm afraid, but a patch for 11.10 would be welcome.

Comment: this is what i was looking 4 in the natty's unity. it is made by ubuntu and u can make it again work the same way in the other releases of unity i guess :)). the second video in the link. http://www.zdnet.com/blog/perlow/ubuntu-linux-1104-a-whale-of-changes-for-canonicals-user-base/16125